# where is this sloka from: "Jīvana muktā api punar bandhanaṁ jānatī karma bhī "

Tags: scripture, vedas, mantras, upanishads

I am trying to identify the source of this shloka,

> Jīvana muktā api punar bandhanaṁ jānatī karma bhī

जीवन मुक्ता अपि पुनर बंधनं जानती कर्म भी

researched online but couldn't find anything relevant, any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Nāradaparivrājaka Upanishad discusses the properties of Jivanmukta. Is that what you are searching for?

Comment: I am looking for the reference source of this shloka, I came across this in an audio lecture, does Nāradaparivrājaka Upanishad have anything matching this?

Comment: It does has stuff related to jivanmukta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from a gaudiya vaishnav text called [Shri Gaudiya Kantahara](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shri-gaudiya-kanthahara/d/doc82210.html)

> **Verse 12:32**

> jīvan-muktā api punar-bandhanaṃ yānti karmabhiḥ
> yady-acintya-mahā-śaktau bhagavaty-aparādhinaḥ